# Create a Custom Compositor Node in Blender editing the Source Code using Visual Studio

Tags: c, visual-studio-2015, blender

I'm trying to create a custom node for the Compositor Node tree in blender. 
I've searched online and it seems to be impossible to create it using python so I had to edit the source code and add the node inside there. Using C will also improve the speed of the node.

I have installed the "Blender developement Toolset" using [This Article](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Doc/Building_Blender/Windows/msvc/CMake) from blender wiki, and then I followed the instructions from the section Building from within the Visual Studio IDE.

This gave me a Blender.sln (Visual Studio Solution) file, that I opened and got me into the source file of Blender. In the source Code I can see a bf-nodes packet inside of which there is the code for each node. I tried to follow this tutorial: https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/User:Nazg-gul/WritingNewNode, but it only explains input and output codes aswell as the basics of an operation. I could not find where to create the file and how to set the node name and id and so on. Furthermore the section for creating a tile-based operation is not completed. 
So should I do to create a custom node? And if the answer would be too long, are there some good tutorials on how to do that?

Comment: I haven't created a node in C++ but from experimenting with pynodes, a node connected to yours will get the value of the socket that it connects to, the getter for that value can calculate the value to pass on, it is a pull based system where you calculate the value when the following node requests it, similarly you get needed values from your input sockets. In the example it looks like `MathAddOperation` is a class that has an `executePixel` method that does the work for each tile. Have a look at [this code review](https://developer.blender.org/D2649) as it adds a new composite node.